# Google Search API - Pricing and free quota

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I noticed that Google changed their pricing model for the Search API. There is no more a price difference between "Simple" and "Complex" queries. In their [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Java_Search_API_pricing) it is just said "Queries". But for some reason the free quota is still differentiating between these two, even when the definitions themselves for "Complex" or "Simple" are gone from the docs.

Can someone please explain this issue ? If there is a rationality behind the free quota seperation, what is considered now a complex query ? What is simple ?

Thanks.

Comment: I know geopoint based searches are complex.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood where is it documented ?
I have a query containing AND and less-than/greater operators on number fields. Im sure this was considered as a simple query but now it is complex.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> `Index.search()`: There are separate quotas for simple and complex
>   queries. A query is complex if its query string includes the name of a
>   geopoint field or at least one OR or NOT boolean operator. A query is
>   also complex if it uses query options to specify non-default sorting
>   or scoring, field expressions, or snippets. Otherwise the query is
>   simple.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Comment: Dont know how i missed that... Thanks. But this doesnt explain why a query that doesnt has an OR or NOT and in the query options only sets a limit is considered complex.

Comment: Also, if in a billable app there is no difference between the 2 query types, why do that for the free quota ?

Comment: Perhaps to encourage optimization. But, I'm afraid, the best answer you are likely to get is "that's how Google wants it to be".

Comment: Google is saying SO is the [official channel for development questions about GAE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/Stack$20Overflow%7Csort:relevance/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w/Jf1OcUK4cF0J). So can someone from the App Engine team maybe answer that ?